# How to write excel formula with Nix library? vb .net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I tried to create a file with decimal numbers on cells (F1:F4), but when i am going to insert a formula to the cell, it's show it like a string. 
Code:

```
s1("F5").Formula = "=SUMME(F1:F4)"
s1("F5").Value = s1("F5").Formula
```

i tried:

```
s1("F5").Formula = "=SUMME(F1:F4)"
s1("F5").Formatting.HiddenFormula = False
s1("F5").Value = s1("F5").Formula
```

i tried:

```
s1("F5").Formula = "=SUMME(F1:F4)"
```

The result its the same, on cell F5, =SUMME(F1:F4)
always on string format.
Note : s1 = Sheet1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s1.Cells("F5").Formula = "=SUM(F1:F4)"
```

You didn't set the range of the sheet. Also changed the SUMME to SUM, unless you have a User Defined Function (UDF) which is called SUMME or you are using Excel in a language where Summe = Sum.

EDIT:

After looking into the library you are using, I would try the following:

```
s1["F5"].Value = "=SUMME(F1:F4)";
```

Comment: Friend, the method Range, don't exist. The word SUMME, it's because the excel it's a german version.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise you are using Vb.net... How about using Cells, updated my answer...

Comment: Sorry friend, again Cells method don't exist. Some existing methods: GetCellRange. I can put the formula but always is in string format. I used this library, [link](https://github.com/lafriks/nix-spreadsheet/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. With that library, it's not possible. 
I used another library just to make the formula. Nix library it's good to add data to the cells.